# Logging Out Using PHP

Tags: php, session, logout

I have seen other programs regarding this but I can't seem to make it work. What am I doing wrong? 
What I want to achieve is that after the user is logged out, going back to previous pages will become restricted.

I have 3 php files:

```
1. sample.php - my main page where username and password is filled in
2. successful.php - the user's page after successfully logging in
3. logout.php - destorys the session which will hinder the user to access pages after logging out
```

sample.php

```
</html>
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td>Password:</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>


<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "login";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$uname=$_POST['username'];  //username
$pw=$_POST['password'];     //password

//to check if all fields are filled in
if(!$uname | !$pw){
    echo "<script>
    window.alert('All fields required!');
    window.location.href='sample.php';
    </script>";
}


else{
$query = "SELECT * from login_users_new WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$pw'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo "<script>
            window.alert('Login Succesfull!')
            window.location.href='successful.php'
            </script>";
}
else{
    echo "<script>
    window.alert('Wrong combination!');
    window.location.href='sample.php';
    </script>";
}

}
}
?>
```

successful.php

```
<h1>CONGRATS</h1>

<h1><a href="logout.php">Logout here</a> </h1>  

</html>
```

logout.php

```
  <?php  
    session_start(); 
    session_destroy();  
    header("Location: sample.php"); 
    ?>
```

What should I add/modify?

Comment: on successful.php check whether session exist or not? by using isset function

Comment: How do I do that? What conditions should be set on isset?

Comment: after successful login create session, at the time of logout unset that session, between these two check whether that session set or not... this is not class room pls

Comment: The only time you use sessions is on your logout page.... You don't ever set a session, so the user is essentially never logged in....

Comment: each and every page check whether session is set

Answer (score 0):

You should put `session_start()` in every single file (so also sample.php, and successful.php) where you want to get your session and that session to persist. (You should call this function before anything else goes to the browser)

[session_start() Official Documatiotion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

You shall follow this basic workout for your system

**Step 1 :**

In your page where your check the user count and if it is great than `0` you're redirecting the user to `succesful.php` You should do another thing too..

i.e., To start the session with some unique thing.. I assume you have id as a primary key  in the table.  So i am creating id as a session name (You can have anything that you wish )

*Code :*

```
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    session_start();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $_SESSION['id']=$result['id'];
        echo "<script>
                window.alert('Login Succesfull!')
                window.location.href='successful.php'
                </script>";
    }
```

**Step 2 :**

In your success page, you should allow the content only if the user is logged in, else you need to redirect the user to logout page

*Code :*

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
{ // If the session is set, you can display the page
?>
<h1>CONGRATS</h1>

<h1><a href="logout.php">Logout here</a> </h1>  

</html>
<?php
}
else
{
  // else redirect the user to logoutpage, which will destroy other sessions and redirect him to index page back
  header('Location : logout.php');
}
?>
```

**Step 3 :**

In your Logout page, you should destroy the session and redirect the use back to index page

*Code :*

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php"); // I am using index.php you can change this page to your need
?>
```

And it is for the beginner level, you can have more workaround to make your system more secured.

Comment: You need `session_start();` on every page that you're going to use sessions on. (*you haven't mentioned this anywhere on the success page*)